# The set of all strings with twice as many 0's as 1's

Tags: automata

I have to create a PDA that accepts  strings with twice as many 0's as 1's. So far I have decided to create one which accepts via empty state:

(q0, 0, Z0) - (q1, 0)

(q0, 1, Z0) - (q1, 11)

(q1, 1, 1) - (q1, 111)

(q1, 0, 1) - (q1, e)

Now when I get to this situation I am not sure how to proceed

(q1, 1, 0) - ?

Comment: What is the meaning of $Z_0$?
And can you use $\rightarrow$ or $\leftarrow$ instead of -?

Comment: What you should do is write down (with sentences !) the mecanism or algorithm you want to implement, and then writing the PDA itself.